# how do I repair broken pipe under foundation

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

For a home built in 1965, with broken pipe under foundation, what is status of inserting a stent, perhaps under visualization?

Comment: What kind of pipe is it?  Steel/galvanized?  Copper?  Black pipe?  Lead?

Comment: Sorry but I must ask how do you know that pipe has broken and how do you know that it is under foundation. I’m asking because it is really hard to determine that.

Answer (score 1):

Broken/damaged drain pipes can be internally lined with a resin impregnated sleeve. There are limitations on size, size and type of damage, type of pipe, access, and pipe configuration. Check out this video: 
[trenchless liner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEUQtwIwBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D6cxwWqWeacQ&ei=xUweVMuiDcagigL9pIDoBw&usg=AFQjCNFckMM2VeVWJ5ueNG8eWChFoalQfQ)

Comment: [This Old House episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFIcRlAOFw0) of re-lining a sewer pipe.

Comment: This problem is very often caused by tree roots growing into the pipe. This problem could come back even after the sleeve is installed unless the 'root' cause of the problem is taken care of.

Comment: "Dig" the root cause pun : ) The trenchless liner guys in my hood guarantee it will stand up for 15 years, roots be damned. Check with your local outfit, you may not have to remove the tree.